# Did COMMON removed?

Tags: linker, elf

I created following c file and compiled to relocatable object file :

```
int x;
static int y;
int* z;
int t = 0;
```

I guess that x and z go to `COMMON` in the symbol table and y and t go to `.bss`. I saw that all symbols went into `.bss`. Did `COMMON` removed from the ELF?